# Telerik MVC hierarchy grid, editor popup, get parent data in JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I've been doing a lot of searching, and can't seem to find any examples that work.

I will simplify the code here as i have a very large telerik mvc hierarchy grid. Here's a child template a few levels down, i need parent information for the previous level.

```
<script id="leagueTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<LeagueViewModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=LeagueTypeId#")
            .ToolBar(toolbar =>
            {
                toolbar.Create().Text("Add New League(Window)");
            })
            .Events(e => e.Edit("leagueEdit")) // this function runs
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.LeagueID))
                .Read(read => read.Action("Bound_League_Read", "Configuration", new { _leagueTypeId = "#=LeagueTypeId#" }))
                .Create(create => create.Action("League_Create", "Configuration").Data("getHeirarchyData")) // this function doesnt run
            )
                )
</script>

            function getHeirarchyData() {
                    console.log("get heirachy data"); // never runs
            }

            function leagueEdit(e) {

                // this runs
                // not sure how to get parent data from e

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to solve this, and if so i'll check your answer but maybe this will help someone in the meantime.

I solved this by setting default values for the model which works excellent except only for string values because of the way i have to access the values as template syntax strings. So i just added string value equivalents for my hierarchy fields to the model.

```
            .Model(model =>
              {
                model.Id(p => p.LeagueID);
                model.Field(l => l.strSportId).DefaultValue("#=SportId#");
                model.Field(l => 
                l.strLeagueTypeId).DefaultValue("#=LeagueTypeId#");
              }
            )
```

Then when i called the edit function, i could get the values like this:

```
function leagueEdit(e) {
     var sportId = parseInt(e.model.strSportId);
     var leagueTypeId = parseInt(e.model.strLeagueTypeId);
}
```